# Did Smilodon become extinct because they were too specialized carnivorous?

Tags: extinction

Specialized in two senses,

1. Teeth were too big. I.e. too specialized to hunt.
2. Only hunted large herbivores

[image]

Comment: Have you done any effort on your part, like going through peer-reviewed articles?

Answer (score 1):

Smilodons were specialized on hunting large herbivores. The decline of Smilodons comes with the decline of these large herbivores. The large herbivores were indeed progressively replaced by faster and more agile herbivores such as deers. The extinction of these large herbivores is at least partially caused by humans. It is possible also that humans may have been in competition over territory and not only food source. As the Smilodons got extinct, smaller species of feline slowly evolved.

Just have a look at [wikipedia > Smilodon#Extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smilodon#Extinction) for more info